# Django custom model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.10 and Oracle 12c. Currently the Django Oracle backend (utilizing cx_oracle) doesn't support XMLType table columns. This means I've had to so far use work-arounds (annotations) to query my legacy tables that use XMLType fields.

Now I'm adding unit tests and I need a better solution to handle these XML fields. I've created a custom field which follows. This successfully allows the migrations scripts to create the tables properly in my test database. However creating fixtures doesn't work because the model can't create the appropriate SQL on it's own.

**So my question is, how do I add to the custom field to call an Oracle function when the ORM generates a select query?**

```
from django.db import models


class XmlField(models.TextField):
   def db_type(self, connection):
      return 'XMLType'

   def ???some_function_I_don't_know???(self, connection):
      #custom_sql_function being an oracle function we created to return
      #the value of an XMLType field
      return 'custom_sql_function(%s)' % self.db_column
```

Comment: did you figure out how to get the test DB to build XMLTYPE columns? so that, for instance, Oracle XQUERY functions in views work in tests?

Comment: btw, cx_Oracle 7.1.0.dev0 on github allow python / django to read XMLTYPE columns as strings...